# Is this fixup to FNV-1a hash a good idea or a bad idea?

Tags: hash, hashcode, fnv

```
algorithm fnv-1 is
    hash := FNV_offset_basis

    for each byte_of_data to be hashed do
        hash := hash XOR byte_of_data
        hash := hash × FNV_prime
        hash := hash XOR multiply_carry

    return hash
```

Where `multiply_carry` is the high half of the multiplication result that doesn't fit in the variable `hash`?

Basically there's two problems with FNV; 1) the tendency to increase the number of set bits due to multiplicative bias, and 2) the low bit problem where the low bit is the XOR of only the low bits of the input.

My experience with lesser hashes (namely those that depend on MOD prime number at the end) says that this reliably fixes the bit bias but I'm not actually sure this works here.

Lifting the code from [recursive's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77991009/14768) and expanding out the definition of FNV1a yields:

```cs
const uint FnvOffsetBasis32 = 2166136261;
const uint FnvPrime32 = 0x01000193;
long totalPop = 0;

for (long i = 0; i <= uint.MaxValue; i++)
{
    uint hash = FnvOffsetBasis32;
    hash ^= (uint)(i) & 255;
    hash *= FnvPrime32;
    hash ^= (uint)(i >> 8) & 255;
    hash *= FnvPrime32;
    hash ^= (uint)(i >> 16) & 255;
    hash *= FnvPrime32;
    hash ^= (uint)(i >> 24) & 255;
    hash *= FnvPrime32;
    //totalPop += uint.PopCount((uint)i * FnvPrime32);
    totalPop += uint.PopCount(hash);
}

const long totalInts = 0x1_0000_0000;

// Expected population: 68,719,476,736
Console.WriteLine("Expected population: {0:0,0}", 16 * totalInts);

// Actual population: 68,719,435,411
Console.WriteLine("Actual population: {0:0,0}", totalPop);
```

Note despite the fact we're kicking around C# demo code, this question isn't in C#. The actual usage is for page-aligned hashtables.

Comment: Look into [SMHasher](https://github.com/rurban/smhasher)

Comment: @bryc: No, sorry, that's really bad advice. You don't use a crypto hash for a hashtable.

Comment: What? Of course not, I'm not implying that you use SHA-3 in your hash table. I'm saying if you want to improve a hash function you should use a proper test suite, which is fair advice. FNV-1a is a very old and weak function, even for hash tables. There are far better general non-crypto hash functions out there more suited to modern platforms.

Comment: @bryc: SMHasher thinks all non-crypto hashes are bad.

Comment: SMHasher is not sentient. There may be people who don't understand the tests and misinterpret the data, believing every reported issue is equally catastrophic, but having sensitive measuring tools is important for those who design and test these functions. Otherwise you're working in the dark. Same goes for PractRand etc. Test suites are important.

Comment: @bryc: Bold of you to think I can't measure. recursive and I have sat down and measured much already; far more than you see here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the next person coming by here; the immediate answer, is no, this doesn't work.

The bit bias in FNV-1a is real. The bit bias in the low 16 bits is worse than in the upper bits.

However, the proposed fix makes it worse. The simple transform that works wonders on mod-prime hashes just doesn't apply; must be something to with the FNV primes.

I'm still looking for really good ides, but they aren't easy to come by.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bit bias.  I've written some test code in C# to do the multiplication step across all possible values of `hash` for the 32 bit variant of the function.  The cumulative result shows an average of *precisely* 16 bits set per output across all possible inputs.

```cs
const int FnvPrime32 = 0x01000193;
long totalPop = 0;

for (long i = int.MinValue; i <= int.MaxValue; i++) {
    totalPop += int.PopCount((int)i * FnvPrime32);
}

const long totalInts = 0x1_0000_0000;

// Expected population: 68,719,476,736
Console.WriteLine("Expected population: {0:0,0}", 16 * totalInts);

// Actual population: 68,719,476,736
Console.WriteLine("Actual population: {0:0,0}", totalPop);
```

Since there is no bit-bias in the algorithm, no fix-up could be advantageous.

Comment: There is a bit bias in the FNV algorithm. If there were no bit bias there would exist a length 4 input that could could produce the 0 hash; however the shortest input that produces a 0 hash is length 5.

Comment: We must be working from different algorithms. For me `FNV1a_32([204,36,49,196]) == 0`.

Comment: I started scratching my head; checked the documentation, there is no 0 value for FNV-1 (not 1a) of length 4; looked at the algorithm, couldn't see how it changed the bit bias with the difference, expanded out the definition of FNV1a_32 using your template, and found there is a bit bias.